# How much score could be earned from answers in one day?

Tags: support, reputation, upvotes

I know that 200 is the reputation upper bound for one day (for upvoting answers). But is there an upper bound for earned upvoting score?

Comment: Int32.MaxValue?

Comment: @canon actually only 1,750,630, as that’s the current number of users having the privilege to upvote.

Comment: what is the most upvotes any single post gained in a single day?

Comment: @KevinB  [1434](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2685541/621962), if SEDE is to be trusted. Pity it's locked; I'd upvote too.

Comment: @Holger for some values of "only"

Comment: @MathieuGuindon compared to Int32.MaxValue…

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, there is currently no limit to the score of any post, either by day or post lifetime. (Or any other possible limit that you can think of- I can only imagine the two cases myself.)

The thought process behind the reputation limit was to prevent people from gaining privileges too quickly, which would (in theory) defeat the idea that the privileges are given to people who know the site well.

Post scores, however, are there to show how the collective voters on the post feel about that post. If the score of a post were capped, then that would skew the representation of how a post is received. It could cause people to vote less, in case their votes were not accepted, or if a person were to vote and it not be accepted because of the limit, they may forget to come back, or feel that their opinion of the posts don't matter.

Comment: I was under the impression that the question was about a cap on _rep gained_ from a post, not the displayed _post score_. Since hitting your daily rep cap doesn't stop people from upvoting your posts (afaik), I disagree with your last paragraph that there can't be a per-post _rep gain_ limit (what the question was) just because there can't be a _post score_ limit (what your answer is talking about). Not that I would advocate for either.

Comment: @MaxLanghof _"I know that 200 is the reputation upper bound for one day ... But is there an upper bound for earned upvoting **score**?"_ From the question. The OP has been around long enough that I'm quite confident they know the difference between post score and rep earned from a post. As for your disagreement... I admit I'm puzzled. I felt I made it clear that the paragraph is talking about the displayed score of the post, and has _nothing_ to do with rep. Admittedly, I also have no idea how you got "rep gain per post limit" from the post when it specifically calls out _post score_...

Answer (score 14):

No; you can continue to accrue post and tag score as long as you're being upvoted.  As you correctly observe, you won't receive reputation for your score gain.

Comment: but you can get bronze, silver & gold badge. There's no tagscore repcap.